# Django: Why is this simple tag not working?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have following simple tag registered in my django 1.7 setup using python 3:

```
# templatetags/getKonten.py    
from django import template
from bilanz.models import Konto

register = template.Library()

def getKonten():
    '''Description...'''

    konten = Konto.objects.all()

    return konten

register.simple_tag(getKonten)
```

When I try to access the simple tag in the template I only get this output: `[, , , ]` . It looks like it's an empty list. But the Konto table is not empty! I want to iterate over all the objects from the query set. This is how I call the template tag in the template:

```
{% load getKonten %}

{% block content %}

{% getKonten %} <!-- Output: [, , , ] -->

<!-- the for loop below has no output -->
{% for konto in getKonten %}
    <h2>{{ konto.konto_title }}</h2>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Following simple tag works without problem:

```
from django import template
from bilanz.models import Konto
from bilanz.templatetags.kontoSum import kontoSum

register = template.Library()

def totalSum(kontotype):
    konten = Konto.objects.filter(konto_type=kontotype).filter(konto_type2='-')
    sum = 0

    for konto in konten:
        sum += kontoSum(konto.id, konto.konto_type)

    return sum

register.simple_tag(totalSum)
```

I really don't see what the problem is!

UPDATE: This is the models.py:

```
class Konto(models.Model):
    konto_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    konto_anfangsBestand = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    konto_sum = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    konto_erfolgswirksam = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    konto_types = (
        ('A', 'Aktiv'),
        ('P', 'Passiv')
    )
    konto_types2 = (
        ('-', 'nicht erfolgswirksam'),
        ('B', 'Betrieb'),
        ('F', 'Finanz'),
        ('N', 'Neutral'),
        ('S', 'Steuer'),
    )
    konto_types3 = (
        ('UV', 'Umlaufvermögen'),
        ('AV', 'Anlagevermögen'),
        ('kFK', 'kurzfristiges Fremdkapital'),
        ('lFK', 'langfristiges Fremdkapital'),
        ('EK', 'Steuer'),
    )
    konto_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=konto_types)
    konto_type2 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=konto_types2, default='-')
    konto_type3 = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=konto_types3)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.konto_title
```

Comment: Does `Konto` have `__str__` or `__repr__` methods?

Comment: @Simeon-Visser Yes. Added the model to the original question.

Comment: Seems like `konto_title` is empty. Do you still get the `<h2>` tags even though you get no output?

Comment: No, I do not get the <h2> tags, but I found the output in the html sourcecode is: `[<Konto: Post>, <Konto: EK>, <Konto: test>, <Konto: testrrr>]` and not `[, , , ]` as displayed in the browser view. So it actually gets the list but it fails to iterate over it?

Comment: Yes because it returned a `string`, see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `simple_tag` is meant to return a `string`. What you need to use is an `assignment_tag`:

```
@register.assignment_tag
def get_konten():
    return Konto.objects.all()
```

in the template:

```
{% get_konten as konten %}
{% for konto in konten %}
    ...
```